# How to make same function execute different part of the code when called at different intervals

Tags: javascript

Is this even possible to do? I want to use the same function at different intervals. How can I make the function run at 5000 and execute certain part of code within the function.

here is an example to give an idea:

```
 var moto = function(){
   // at 5000 run this part of code
   console.log("did stuff when called at 5000 time interval")

   // at 6000 run this part of code
   console.log("did stuff when called at 6000 time interval")
 }

 window.setInterval(moto, 5000)
 window.setInterval(moto, 6000)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So pass a parameter with the call.

```
 var moto = function( val){
   if(val===5000) {
     // at 5000 run this part of code
     console.log("did stuff when called at 5000 time interval");
   } else {
   // at 6000 run this part of code
     console.log("did stuff when called at 6000 time interval");
   }
 }

 window.setInterval(moto.bind(this, 5000), 5000);
 window.setInterval(moto.bind(this, 6000), 6000);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want it to be the same function, set a delay of the greatest common divisor of the desired delays, in this case `gcd(5000, 6000) = 1000`. And then use a counter.

```js
var counter = 0;
var moto = function() {
  ++counter;
  if (counter % 5 == 0) // at 5000 run this part of code
    console.log("did stuff when called at 5000 time interval")
  if (counter % 6 == 0) // at 6000 run this part of code
    console.log("did stuff when called at 6000 time interval")
};
window.setInterval(moto, 1000);
```

Comment: You may reset the counter when it reaches the least common multiple of the delays.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be pass some param to your functions like:

```
var moto = function(runAt){
   // at 5000 run this part of code
   if(runAt==500)
   console.log("did stuff when called at 5000 time interval")

   // at 6000 run this part of code
   if(runAt==600)
   console.log("did stuff when called at 6000 time interval")
 }

 window.setInterval(function() {moto(500)}, 5000)
 window.setInterval(function() {moto(600)}, 6000)
```

Comment: And that runs once

Comment: @epascarello now it doesn't look like yours anymore

Answer (score 0):

Look another way of doing things :P

```js
class Moto {
  constructor(delay) {
    this.delay = delay
    setInterval(this.fn.bind(this), delay)
  }
  
  fn() {
    // at 5000 run this part of code
    if (this.delay === 5000)  
      console.log("did stuff when called at 5000 time interval")
    
    // at 6000 run this part of code
    if (this.delay === 6000)
      console.log("did stuff when called at 6000 time interval")
  }
}   
   
new Moto(5000)
new Moto(6000)
```